# Prediction with variable lag

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, lags

Imagine I have the very simple following data where I want to predict B based on A1 and A2:

```
A1  A2  B
1   0   1
1   1   1
2   1   1
2   2   1
3   2   2
4   1   3
3   3   2
3   0   3
4   3   4
```

As a human it is very easy to understand that that B is equal to A1 shifted by A2. So to predict B I would need a lagged version A1 where the delay length is available in the column A2.

Do you know if there is any machine learning approach that could detect that kind of relationship by itself automatically - without manually shifting the data in advance?

Thanks